# write data to csv

Tags: jsp, csv, export-to-csv

I am using the below code to create a csv file and write data to csv file.

code to create and write data to CSV file:

```
<%@page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%

response.setHeader("Content-type","text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename="+ "myTest.csv");
String outputData = (String)request.getParameter("outputData");
%>

<%=outputData%>
```

Issue is first 4 rows in the csv file is blank and data is written from 5th line.
How can i write data from first line of csv file or how can i delete the first four empty rows of csv file. I have not used any special API to create a csv/excel file as my requirement is minimal(just to write data into csv/excel file).Please suggest,thanks.

Comment: so someone is copy pasting csv in textarea?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni - outputData which i'm getting through request.getParameter("outputData") contains string of comma separated values which i want to write on csv/excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can only set the content-type once; that is, the last one will be the only one to be sent.
- You should not use the `<%@page...%>` directive, but rather set the Content-Encoding in Java code, to avoid the possibility of closing/opening `<% %>`s causing whitespace (from between `%>` and `<%`) to be printed.
- Same for printing at the end, don't close/open `<% %>`s but use out.print
- Also, for setting content-type, you can use the method specifically for that rather than response.setHeader:

```
    <%
        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
        //response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=myTest.csv");
        String outputData = (String)request.getParameter("outputData");
        out.print(outputData);
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

when the server convert the JSP page to servlet it add implicitly blank lines (\n).
add out.clear() befor writing to clear out object. and dont forget to close out at the end.
ex :

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=myTest.csv");
    String outputData = (String)request.getParameter("outputData");
    out.clear();
    out.print(outputData);
    out.close();
  %>
```

Comment: The out.clear(); directive removes preceding blank lines, otherwise reflected in Excel as blank rows, which is a good formatting idea.